# Cache TTL missing in header in cloudfront object

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have cloudfront distribution configured with S3, when I am accessing the object with s3 url then cache-control is showing in response header. When I access the object from cloudfront url then Cache-Control is missing in header. I have added Cache-Control, Expires both with s3 objects. Attached screenshot is from the cloudfront Behavior settings. How to return Cache-Control in response ?

[image]

Comment: Try invalidating the cache

Comment: @jellycsc Thanks for suggestion, Invalidating kind of worked but not sure if it is the right and best way to make it work.